# DataDog Agent Upgrade on Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, datadog

I'm running an Azure Cloud Service with a WebRole.

We run the DataDog Agent on each of our server instances, by running a startup task that executes a .cmd file.

Previously we have been using the latest version of DataDog Agent 5, and installing it using this -

```
start /w cmd
set log=datadog-install.log
set api_key=%1

sc query | findstr DatadogAgent
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo "Datadog Agent service not detected" >> %log%
    echo "Starting the installation" >> %log%

    if exist ddagent.msi (
        echo "Already has the installer" >> %log%
    ) else (
        echo "Fetching the Agent Installer" >> %log%
        powershell -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/ddagent-windows-stable/ddagent-cli.msi', 'ddagent.msi')"
    )

    echo "Starting the installer" >>%log%
    msiexec.exe /qn /i ddagent.msi APIKEY=%api_key% /L+ %log%
) else (
    echo "Agent already exists, skipping install" >>%log%
)

echo "Finished Install" >>%log%
exit 0
```

Now we are trying to upgrade to the latest version of DataDog Agent 6 using this, which is failing to install and register the instance as an available host in DataDogs dashboard -

```
start /w cmd
set log=datadog-install.log
set api_key=%1

sc query | findstr DatadogAgent
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo "Datadog Agent service not detected" >> %log%
    echo "Starting the installation" >> %log%

    if exist ddagent.msi (
        echo "Already has the installer" >> %log%
    ) else (
        echo "Fetching the Agent Installer" >> %log%
        powershell -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/ddagent-windows-stable/datadog-agent-6-latest.amd64.msi', 'ddagent.msi')"
    )

    echo "Starting the installer" >>%log%
    msiexec.exe /qn /i ddagent.msi APIKEY=%api_key% /L+ %log%
) else (
    echo "Agent already exists, skipping install" >>%log%
)

echo "Finished Install" >>%log%
exit 0
```

The URL is of course different in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Windows OS is D drive, the setting is installed in `D:\ProgramData\Datadog`.
Copying it to `C:\ProgramData\Datadog` will work, but I submitted an improvement request to Datadog Support.

Comment: @Goober fixed [On Windows, the agent now properly computes the location of ProgramData for configuration files instead of using hardcoded values](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#680)